# GUI button ActionListeners

Tags: java, eclipse

In my GUI program I have 4 sets of cards and I want to add an action listener to each Card button so that when it's clicked it goes invisible. I've tried the source.setVisible(), however it still doesn't work. I think my problem is that I created all the Card buttons through for loops, but I'm not entirely sure though.

```
    import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
    import java.awt.Dimension;
    import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
    import java.awt.Image;
    import java.awt.Insets;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import javax.swing.border.Border;
    import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
    import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.JTextField;
    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
    public class CardGame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
private JButton Deal;

CardGame(){
    setTitle("A Card Game");
    setSize(2000, 1000);

    final GridBagConstraints layoutSpec = new GridBagConstraints();
    layoutSpec.gridx = 0;
    layoutSpec.gridy = 0;

    final GridBagConstraints dealSpec = new GridBagConstraints();
    layoutSpec.gridx = 4;
    layoutSpec.gridy = 4;

    final GridBagConstraints dealSpecs = new GridBagConstraints();
    layoutSpec.gridx = 7;
    layoutSpec.gridy = 7;


    JPanel cardA = new JPanel();
    cardA.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
    add(cardA, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    for(int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {   //Loop that Creates a Hand of Cards for Hand A
        cardA.add(new JButton("Card A-" + Integer.toString(i+1)), layoutSpec);
    }

    JPanel cardB = new JPanel();
    cardB.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
    add(cardB, BorderLayout.EAST);
    for(int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {   //Loop that Creates a Hand of Cards for Hand B
        cardB.add(new JButton("Card B-" + Integer.toString(i+1)), layoutSpec);
    }

    JPanel cardC = new JPanel();
    cardC.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
    add(cardC, BorderLayout.WEST);
    for(int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {   //Loop that Creates a Hand of Cards for Hand C
        cardC.add(new JButton("Card C-" + Integer.toString(i+1)), layoutSpec);
    }

    JPanel cardD = new JPanel();
    cardD.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
    add(cardD, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    for(int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {   //Loop that Creates a Hand of Cards for Hand D
        cardD.add(new JButton("Card D-" + Integer.toString(i+1)), layoutSpec);
    }

    JPanel fillCenter = new JPanel();
    fillCenter.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
    add(fillCenter, BorderLayout.CENTER);   //Adds a panel that fills the center of the JFrame
    fillCenter.add(new JButton("Deal"), dealSpec);  //Adds a Deal Button on top of the fillCenter JPanel
    fillCenter.add(new JButton("Reset"), dealSpecs);    //Adds a Reset Button on top of the fillCenter JPanel

}
@Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
    if(event.getSource() == (Deal)){

    };
    if(event.getSource() == ("Deal"));
    for(int i = 0; i < 13; i++){
        if(event.getSource() == ("Card " + Integer.toString(i+1)));
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    CardGame cards = new CardGame();
    cards.setVisible(true);
    return;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

try this `((JButton)event.getSource()).setVisible(false);`